# ANTLR ID gets mixed with lexer rule

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer

I have been working on a grammar for a long time but now when I'm trying it out on a big code base I get this annoying problem. When I'm trying to parse an ID, for example "INDEX", and I have another rule that looks for 'INDEX' the parser fails. I have created an example grammar for illustrating the problem:

```
public variable : '@' ID '=' STRING;
index : INDEX;
WS : (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {Skip();};
INDEX : 'INDEX';    
ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
STRING : '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'\'') )* '\'';
```

So when I'm trying to parse "`@some = 'some'`" it works fine, but "`@index = 'some'`" gives me `{<mismatched token: [@1,1:5='index',<8>,1:1], resync=@index='some'>}`

Output is an AST in C#.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you create a variable name lexer rule?

```
public VARIABLENAME : '@' ID
```

This way the keywords would still work, but woudln't interfere with the variable names.

The `variable` rule would be modified to:

```
public variable : VARIABLENAME '=' STRING;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your grammar without "INDEX" rule and check this rule manually in your C# code of AST traversal.

Comment: If I exclude the index lexer rule it works, but in my bigger grammar i have hundred of those. So then i need to remove all words in my grammar and check them after... Doesn't make sense to me to parse everything as IDs and process them afterwards. Is that the way it should work?